# Data Chart lotus note designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I'm searching in the web about how to make charts on lotus notes designer, I see some .ntf file but I don't know how to use it. my question how to make a chart? I have the data but it's possible to make a chart on lotus domino?

Comment: You could look into [Notes Reconn](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Notes%20Reconn) and [Java Charts](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/java%20charts).

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do charts with lotus notes, but no native one.

1. Export to Excel
2. Use an Applet or ActiveX component
3. Use XPages an jchart/dojo/jquery plugins to have some nice charts on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at a javascript charting package and using either xpage or 'classic' domino development techniques to interface domino data to the browser based library. Charts using SVG and powerful js libraries can rival or even surpass excel and many active-x solutions. My favorite and one of the most powerful is [http://www.highcharts.com/](http://www.highcharts.com/%20highcharts)

This is licensed software - Other free/open source packages are available.